# What adhesive should I use for Carbon Fiber and Painted metal?

Tags: adhesives

I have a tripod that has carbon fiber tubes.  There is a metal end piece on the center tube that has fallen out.  What kind of glue/adhesive should I use to reattach it?

[image: broken tripod tube]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend two-part epoxy resin, and the addition of a pin. Basically you would:

- pre-drill a hole through the tube and the cap
- mix the resin
- apply resin to both the inside of the tube and the cap
- join the two pieces with a nut and bolt

EDIT
Looking at your pic again, I see that there is a place for a screw to lock in the cap. Maybe take it to a hardware store and figure out if it’s an M4 or M6 and use the screw instead of drilling again...